# How to enable auto-login for my Guild Wars account?

Tags: guild-wars

How can I log in to my Guild Wars Account automatically when I launch the Game Client?

Comment: Command line parameters.  `-email` and `-password` if I remember correctly...but I'm not sure enough to give an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add some command line arguments to Gw.exe when you start the game up.

The two that you need to add are `-email`, `-character`, and `-password`.  Have a look at this link for more complete details:

> http://wiki.guildwars.com/wiki/Command_line_arguments

From the link:

> Instead of using the command line, you can execute switches directly from your Guild Wars shortcut:
>   1. Right click on your Guild Wars shortcut and select 'Properties'.
>   2. In the 'Target Area' field you will see the location of your Guild Wars executable file:
>   "<...>\Guild Wars\Gw.exe"
>   3. Write the desired command line arguments after the quote marks, each beginning with a space:
>   "<...>\Guild Wars\Gw.exe" -perf -windowed

Comment: Beat me to it, by mere seconds!

I'd also note, that putting your password in plain text in a short cut is bad juju.

Comment: @Zemm that is true, especially if other people have access to your machine.

Comment: Are there work arounds?

Comment: You also need the name of one of your characters nowadays

Answer (score 3):

Create a shortcut to the gw.exe or edit its properties and add following options after “C:\Program Files\Guild Wars\gw.exe”
-email mail(at)provider.end -character "Name Of Your Charakter" -password qwerasdf

**Be aware: Your password is saved in cleartext!**

Other command line options can be found on [GuildWiki](http://guildwars.wikia.com/wiki/Command_line)